# run console application in C# with parameters

Tags: c#, console-application

How can I run a console application in C#, passing parameters to it, and get the result of the  application in Unicode? `Console.WriteLine` is used in the console application.
Important point is write Unicode in Console Application.

Comment: Lots of posts.  The console only supports 8-bit character encodings.  Technically you can switch the Console.OutputEncoding to utf8.  That is not going to look good if you ever run it without redirection.  Using a file instead would be a good idea.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Sample from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput.aspx)

```
 // Start the child process.
 Process p = new Process();
 // Redirect the output stream of the child process.
 p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
 p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
 p.StartInfo.FileName = "Write500Lines.exe";
 p.Start();
 // Do not wait for the child process to exit before
 // reading to the end of its redirected stream.
 // p.WaitForExit();
 // Read the output stream first and then wait.
 string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
 p.WaitForExit();
```

Answer (score 5):

Check out `Process.Start()`:

[MSDN - Process.Start Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5.aspx)

Your code will probably look something like:

```
var process = Process.Start(pathToProgram, argsString);

process.WaitForExit();

var exitCode = process.ExitCode;
```

If by "result of the console application" you mean any output of the program to the console while it runs...you'll need to look at the documentation and figure out how to redirect the output of the program from the console to another stream.

Answer (score 5):

try with below code, here "Amay" is a argument.

```
 System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo info = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(@"E:\\ConsoleApplicationt\bin\Debug\ConsoleApplicationt.exe", "Amay");

 System.Diagnostics.Process p = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(info);
```

Answer (score 3):

Here http://www.aspcode.net/ProcessStart-and-redirect-standard-output.aspx You can see how to read the output from the console app You start with Process.Start().

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) class. You can call any executable using Process.Start("myexe.exe");

Answer (score 1):

You should be careful depending upon your use some of the other examples can have issues.  For common mistakes made writing your own code, read "[How to use System.Diagnostics.Process correctly](http://csharptest.net/?p=321)"

For a library to use, there is one here: http://csharptest.net/browse/src/Library/Processes
with a brief usage guide: "[Using the ProcessRunner class](http://csharptest.net/?p=319)"