# Call exe with special method

Tags: c#

I have one exe file in special folder in my PC.
My folder is: `D:\Program Files (x86)\FXDD - MetaTrader`
My exe name: `metalang.exe`
This exe compile files and make with new format.
My sample file is for example: `vfc.mq4`

When want execute this exe, from Command Prompt(cmd) I call that same below:
`D:\Program Files (x86)\FXDD - MetaTrader\metalang.exe vfc.mq4`
and it compile file for me.

Question is here:
How do this process in C#? 
I know this function works for call exe:

```
Process.Start("C:\\");
```

I dont know how call vfc.mq4 and what must be format?

Regards;

Comment: Look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4h05yb.aspx) for your answer. You can use `ProcessStartInfo` to pass in command line parameters

Answer (score 1):

If you read the documentation, you'll see the `Process.Start()` can take *two* parameters – one for the filename of the EXE and one for the command-line arguments.

Comment: I do same this:
string str1 = "D:\\Program Files (x86)\\FXDD - MetaTrader\\metalang.exe";
            string str2 = "D:\\Program Files (x86)\\FXDD - MetaTrader\\VFX.mq4";
            Process.Start(str1, str2);
But not works.
Format must be different?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
var process = Process.Start(pathToProgram, argsString);

process.WaitForExit();

var exitCode = process.ExitCode;
```

on argsString use the path to "vfc.mq4".

Hope it helps!

*Font:* [run console application in C# with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6511978/run-console-application-in-c-sharp-with-parameters)

Comment: Have you tried Ken White comment? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17321289/use-process-start-with-parameters-and-spaces-in-path