# Retrieve information about digital signature of a non-exe file?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, digital-signature, digital-certificate

I know that I can use the following code to retrieve information about a digital signature of an executable file using [X509Certificate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate.createfromsignedfile(v=vs.110).aspx) class:

```
X509Certificate cert = X509Certificate.CreateFromSignedFile("MySignedProgram.exe");
string certSubject = cert.Subject;
```

My question is how to retrieve a digital certificate details from a non-exe file, for instance, a signed `.js` or `.vbs` file?

PS. [This native code](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/323809) and [CryptQueryObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380264(v=vs.85).aspx) API seem to do the job correctly. But I'm curious if there's an analogy for it in .NET? The code above throws an exception with error code `0x80092009` and description `Cannot find the requested object` if I pass "MySignedScript.js" to `CreateFromSignedFile` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I want to post an update since I haven't gotten an answer to my original question (for whoever else may be dealing with this.)

I was able to resolve this by doing it the hard way, i.e. by getting the digital certificate details from an unmanaged process.

The good news is that there's a [good C sample](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/323809) from Microsoft that shows how it's done. The bad news is that it doesn't seem to work if you rewrite that C code for .NET using PInvoke. (I don't know PInvoke well enough to tell you why. So if anyone knows, I'd like to know too. So please share it in the comments below.)

So the only way how I managed to get it to work is by making a small C++ console executable using the [Microsoft code](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/323809) and call it from a C# process. The trick is passing parameters to and from it. You can use command line arguments to pass parameters in, but to get them out, you can use the `STDOUT` stream. ([Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6511978/843732) an example for that.)

Lastly, here's my reasoning why I was getting an exception with the `0x80092009` error code, which is, btw, `CRYPT_E_NO_MATCH` in WinAPI world. Most certainly that error was generated by the [`CryptQueryObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380264(v=vs.85).aspx) API. Unfortunately, like anything else with Microsoft, that error is too vague to provide any additional details for the failure. For instance, it may be returned if any of the input parameters to the `CryptQueryObject` API itself were misconfigured. But by playing with the Microsoft's C code I learned that the `CryptQueryObject` API relies on the code-signed file's extension for its correct interpretation of the format of the attached digital signature. For instance, if it's an executable file it would be a digital format for the signature. If it's a `JScript` file, the signature will have another format, the third format will be used for a `VBScript` file, or for `PowerShell` script, and so on. So quite possibly, the managed `X509Certificate` class renames the target file that causes the `CryptQueryObject` API to fail. This doesn't explain though, why PInvoke method seems to fail with the same error code. (Although in this case it may be my lack of knowledge of PInvoke calls that lead to it, since the same error code is returned for bad input parameters.)

Lastly, in case [Microsoft original page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/323809) goes under, here's a copy-and-paste of the C code I'm referring to:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <wincrypt.h>
#include <wintrust.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "crypt32.lib")

#define ENCODING (X509_ASN_ENCODING | PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING)

typedef struct {
    LPWSTR lpszProgramName;
    LPWSTR lpszPublisherLink;
    LPWSTR lpszMoreInfoLink;
} SPROG_PUBLISHERINFO, *PSPROG_PUBLISHERINFO;

BOOL GetProgAndPublisherInfo(PCMSG_SIGNER_INFO pSignerInfo,
                             PSPROG_PUBLISHERINFO Info);
BOOL GetDateOfTimeStamp(PCMSG_SIGNER_INFO pSignerInfo, SYSTEMTIME *st);
BOOL PrintCertificateInfo(PCCERT_CONTEXT pCertContext);
BOOL GetTimeStampSignerInfo(PCMSG_SIGNER_INFO pSignerInfo,
                            PCMSG_SIGNER_INFO *pCounterSignerInfo);

int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR *argv[])
{
    WCHAR szFileName[MAX_PATH]; 
    HCERTSTORE hStore = NULL;
    HCRYPTMSG hMsg = NULL; 
    PCCERT_CONTEXT pCertContext = NULL;
    BOOL fResult;   
    DWORD dwEncoding, dwContentType, dwFormatType;
    PCMSG_SIGNER_INFO pSignerInfo = NULL;
    PCMSG_SIGNER_INFO pCounterSignerInfo = NULL;
    DWORD dwSignerInfo;
    CERT_INFO CertInfo;     
    SPROG_PUBLISHERINFO ProgPubInfo;
    SYSTEMTIME st;

    ZeroMemory(&ProgPubInfo, sizeof(ProgPubInfo));
    __try
    {
        if (argc != 2)
        {
            _tprintf(_T("Usage: SignedFileInfo <filename>\n"));
            return 0;
        }

#ifdef UNICODE
        lstrcpynW(szFileName, argv[1], MAX_PATH);
#else
        if (mbstowcs(szFileName, argv[1], MAX_PATH) == -1)
        {
            printf("Unable to convert to unicode.\n");
            __leave;
        }
#endif

        // Get message handle and store handle from the signed file.
        fResult = CryptQueryObject(CERT_QUERY_OBJECT_FILE,
                                   szFileName,
                                   CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_FLAG_PKCS7_SIGNED_EMBED,
                                   CERT_QUERY_FORMAT_FLAG_BINARY,
                                   0,
                                   &dwEncoding,
                                   &dwContentType,
                                   &dwFormatType,
                                   &hStore,
                                   &hMsg,
                                   NULL);
        if (!fResult)
        {
            _tprintf(_T("CryptQueryObject failed with %x\n"), GetLastError());
            __leave;
        }

        // Get signer information size.
        fResult = CryptMsgGetParam(hMsg, 
                                   CMSG_SIGNER_INFO_PARAM, 
                                   0, 
                                   NULL, 
                                   &dwSignerInfo);
        if (!fResult)
        {
            _tprintf(_T("CryptMsgGetParam failed with %x\n"), GetLastError());
            __leave;
        }

        // Allocate memory for signer information.
        pSignerInfo = (PCMSG_SIGNER_INFO)LocalAlloc(LPTR, dwSignerInfo);
        if (!pSignerInfo)
        {
            _tprintf(_T("Unable to allocate memory for Signer Info.\n"));
            __leave;
        }

        // Get Signer Information.
        fResult = CryptMsgGetParam(hMsg, 
                                   CMSG_SIGNER_INFO_PARAM, 
                                   0, 
                                   (PVOID)pSignerInfo, 
                                   &dwSignerInfo);
        if (!fResult)
        {
            _tprintf(_T("CryptMsgGetParam failed with %x\n"), GetLastError());
            __leave;
        }

        // Get program name and publisher information from 
        // signer info structure.
        if (GetProgAndPublisherInfo(pSignerInfo, &ProgPubInfo))
        {
            if (ProgPubInfo.lpszProgramName != NULL)
            {
                wprintf(L"Program Name : %s\n",
                    ProgPubInfo.lpszProgramName);
            }

            if (ProgPubInfo.lpszPublisherLink != NULL)
            {
                wprintf(L"Publisher Link : %s\n",
                    ProgPubInfo.lpszPublisherLink);
            }

            if (ProgPubInfo.lpszMoreInfoLink != NULL)
            {
                wprintf(L"MoreInfo Link : %s\n",
                    ProgPubInfo.lpszMoreInfoLink);
            }
        }

        _tprintf(_T("\n"));

        // Search for the signer certificate in the temporary 
        // certificate store.
        CertInfo.Issuer = pSignerInfo->Issuer;
        CertInfo.SerialNumber = pSignerInfo->SerialNumber;

        pCertContext = CertFindCertificateInStore(hStore,
                                                  ENCODING,
                                                  0,
                                                  CERT_FIND_SUBJECT_CERT,
                                                  (PVOID)&CertInfo,
                                                  NULL);
        if (!pCertContext)
        {
            _tprintf(_T("CertFindCertificateInStore failed with %x\n"),
                GetLastError());
            __leave;
        }

        // Print Signer certificate information.
        _tprintf(_T("Signer Certificate:\n\n"));        
        PrintCertificateInfo(pCertContext);
        _tprintf(_T("\n"));

        // Get the timestamp certificate signerinfo structure.
        if (GetTimeStampSignerInfo(pSignerInfo, &pCounterSignerInfo))
        {
            // Search for Timestamp certificate in the temporary
            // certificate store.
            CertInfo.Issuer = pCounterSignerInfo->Issuer;
            CertInfo.SerialNumber = pCounterSignerInfo->SerialNumber;

            pCertContext = CertFindCertificateInStore(hStore,
                                                ENCODING,
                                                0,
                                                CERT_FIND_SUBJECT_CERT,
                                                (PVOID)&CertInfo,
                                                NULL);
            if (!pCertContext)
            {
                _tprintf(_T("CertFindCertificateInStore failed with %x\n"),
                    GetLastError());
                __leave;
            }

            // Print timestamp certificate information.
            _tprintf(_T("TimeStamp Certificate:\n\n"));
            PrintCertificateInfo(pCertContext);
            _tprintf(_T("\n"));

            // Find Date of timestamp.
            if (GetDateOfTimeStamp(pCounterSignerInfo, &st))
            {
                _tprintf(_T("Date of TimeStamp : %02d/%02d/%04d %02d:%02d\n"),
                                            st.wMonth,
                                            st.wDay,
                                            st.wYear,
                                            st.wHour,
                                            st.wMinute);
            }
            _tprintf(_T("\n"));
        }
    }
    __finally
    {               
        // Clean up.
        if (ProgPubInfo.lpszProgramName != NULL)
            LocalFree(ProgPubInfo.lpszProgramName);
        if (ProgPubInfo.lpszPublisherLink != NULL)
            LocalFree(ProgPubInfo.lpszPublisherLink);
        if (ProgPubInfo.lpszMoreInfoLink != NULL)
            LocalFree(ProgPubInfo.lpszMoreInfoLink);

        if (pSignerInfo != NULL) LocalFree(pSignerInfo);
        if (pCounterSignerInfo != NULL) LocalFree(pCounterSignerInfo);
        if (pCertContext != NULL) CertFreeCertificateContext(pCertContext);
        if (hStore != NULL) CertCloseStore(hStore, 0);
        if (hMsg != NULL) CryptMsgClose(hMsg);
    }
    return 0;
}

BOOL PrintCertificateInfo(PCCERT_CONTEXT pCertContext)
{
    BOOL fReturn = FALSE;
    LPTSTR szName = NULL;
    DWORD dwData;

    __try
    {
        // Print Serial Number.
        _tprintf(_T("Serial Number: "));
        dwData = pCertContext->pCertInfo->SerialNumber.cbData;
        for (DWORD n = 0; n < dwData; n++)
        {
            _tprintf(_T("%02x "),
              pCertContext->pCertInfo->SerialNumber.pbData[dwData - (n + 1)]);
        }
        _tprintf(_T("\n"));

        // Get Issuer name size.
        if (!(dwData = CertGetNameString(pCertContext, 
                                         CERT_NAME_SIMPLE_DISPLAY_TYPE,
                                         CERT_NAME_ISSUER_FLAG,
                                         NULL,
                                         NULL,
                                         0)))
        {
            _tprintf(_T("CertGetNameString failed.\n"));
            __leave;
        }

        // Allocate memory for Issuer name.
        szName = (LPTSTR)LocalAlloc(LPTR, dwData * sizeof(TCHAR));
        if (!szName)
        {
            _tprintf(_T("Unable to allocate memory for issuer name.\n"));
            __leave;
        }

        // Get Issuer name.
        if (!(CertGetNameString(pCertContext, 
                                CERT_NAME_SIMPLE_DISPLAY_TYPE,
                                CERT_NAME_ISSUER_FLAG,
                                NULL,
                                szName,
                                dwData)))
        {
            _tprintf(_T("CertGetNameString failed.\n"));
            __leave;
        }

        // print Issuer name.
        _tprintf(_T("Issuer Name: %s\n"), szName);
        LocalFree(szName);
        szName = NULL;

        // Get Subject name size.
        if (!(dwData = CertGetNameString(pCertContext, 
                                         CERT_NAME_SIMPLE_DISPLAY_TYPE,
                                         0,
                                         NULL,
                                         NULL,
                                         0)))
        {
            _tprintf(_T("CertGetNameString failed.\n"));
            __leave;
        }

        // Allocate memory for subject name.
        szName = (LPTSTR)LocalAlloc(LPTR, dwData * sizeof(TCHAR));
        if (!szName)
        {
            _tprintf(_T("Unable to allocate memory for subject name.\n"));
            __leave;
        }

        // Get subject name.
        if (!(CertGetNameString(pCertContext, 
                                CERT_NAME_SIMPLE_DISPLAY_TYPE,
                                0,
                                NULL,
                                szName,
                                dwData)))
        {
            _tprintf(_T("CertGetNameString failed.\n"));
            __leave;
        }

        // Print Subject Name.
        _tprintf(_T("Subject Name: %s\n"), szName);

        fReturn = TRUE;
    }
    __finally
    {
        if (szName != NULL) LocalFree(szName);
    }

    return fReturn;
}

LPWSTR AllocateAndCopyWideString(LPCWSTR inputString)
{
    LPWSTR outputString = NULL;

    outputString = (LPWSTR)LocalAlloc(LPTR,
        (wcslen(inputString) + 1) * sizeof(WCHAR));
    if (outputString != NULL)
    {
        lstrcpyW(outputString, inputString);
    }
    return outputString;
}

BOOL GetProgAndPublisherInfo(PCMSG_SIGNER_INFO pSignerInfo,
                             PSPROG_PUBLISHERINFO Info)
{
    BOOL fReturn = FALSE;
    PSPC_SP_OPUS_INFO OpusInfo = NULL;  
    DWORD dwData;
    BOOL fResult;

    __try
    {
        // Loop through authenticated attributes and find
        // SPC_SP_OPUS_INFO_OBJID OID.
        for (DWORD n = 0; n < pSignerInfo->AuthAttrs.cAttr; n++)
        {           
            if (lstrcmpA(SPC_SP_OPUS_INFO_OBJID, 
                        pSignerInfo->AuthAttrs.rgAttr[n].pszObjId) == 0)
            {
                // Get Size of SPC_SP_OPUS_INFO structure.
                fResult = CryptDecodeObject(ENCODING,
                            SPC_SP_OPUS_INFO_OBJID,
                            pSignerInfo->AuthAttrs.rgAttr[n].rgValue[0].pbData,
                            pSignerInfo->AuthAttrs.rgAttr[n].rgValue[0].cbData,
                            0,
                            NULL,
                            &dwData);
                if (!fResult)
                {
                    _tprintf(_T("CryptDecodeObject failed with %x\n"),
                        GetLastError());
                    __leave;
                }

                // Allocate memory for SPC_SP_OPUS_INFO structure.
                OpusInfo = (PSPC_SP_OPUS_INFO)LocalAlloc(LPTR, dwData);
                if (!OpusInfo)
                {
                    _tprintf(_T("Unable to allocate memory for Publisher Info.\n"));
                    __leave;
                }

                // Decode and get SPC_SP_OPUS_INFO structure.
                fResult = CryptDecodeObject(ENCODING,
                            SPC_SP_OPUS_INFO_OBJID,
                            pSignerInfo->AuthAttrs.rgAttr[n].rgValue[0].pbData,
                            pSignerInfo->AuthAttrs.rgAttr[n].rgValue[0].cbData,
                            0,
                            OpusInfo,
                            &dwData);
                if (!fResult)
                {
                    _tprintf(_T("CryptDecodeObject failed with %x\n"),
                        GetLastError());
                    __leave;
                }

                // Fill in Program Name if present.
                if (OpusInfo->pwszProgramName)
                {
                    Info->lpszProgramName =
                        AllocateAndCopyWideString(OpusInfo->pwszProgramName);
                }
                else
                    Info->lpszProgramName = NULL;

                // Fill in Publisher Information if present.
                if (OpusInfo->pPublisherInfo)
                {

                    switch (OpusInfo->pPublisherInfo->dwLinkChoice)
                    {
                        case SPC_URL_LINK_CHOICE:
                            Info->lpszPublisherLink =
                                AllocateAndCopyWideString(OpusInfo->pPublisherInfo->pwszUrl);
                            break;

                        case SPC_FILE_LINK_CHOICE:
                            Info->lpszPublisherLink =
                                AllocateAndCopyWideString(OpusInfo->pPublisherInfo->pwszFile);
                            break;

                        default:
                            Info->lpszPublisherLink = NULL;
                            break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Info->lpszPublisherLink = NULL;
                }

                // Fill in More Info if present.
                if (OpusInfo->pMoreInfo)
                {
                    switch (OpusInfo->pMoreInfo->dwLinkChoice)
                    {
                        case SPC_URL_LINK_CHOICE:
                            Info->lpszMoreInfoLink =
                                AllocateAndCopyWideString(OpusInfo->pMoreInfo->pwszUrl);
                            break;

                        case SPC_FILE_LINK_CHOICE:
                            Info->lpszMoreInfoLink =
                                AllocateAndCopyWideString(OpusInfo->pMoreInfo->pwszFile);
                            break;

                        default:
                            Info->lpszMoreInfoLink = NULL;
                            break;
                    }
                }               
                else
                {
                    Info->lpszMoreInfoLink = NULL;
                }

                fReturn = TRUE;

                break; // Break from for loop.
            } // lstrcmp SPC_SP_OPUS_INFO_OBJID                 
        } // for 
    }
    __finally
    {
        if (OpusInfo != NULL) LocalFree(OpusInfo);      
    }

    return fReturn;
}

BOOL GetDateOfTimeStamp(PCMSG_SIGNER_INFO pSignerInfo, SYSTEMTIME *st)
{   
    BOOL fResult;
    FILETIME lft, ft;   
    DWORD dwData;
    BOOL fReturn = FALSE;

    // Loop through authenticated attributes and find
    // szOID_RSA_signingTime OID.
    for (DWORD n = 0; n < pSignerInfo->AuthAttrs.cAttr; n++)
    {           
        if (lstrcmpA(szOID_RSA_signingTime, 
                    pSignerInfo->AuthAttrs.rgAttr[n].pszObjId) == 0)
        {               
            // Decode and get FILETIME structure.
            dwData = sizeof(ft);
            fResult = CryptDecodeObject(ENCODING,
                        szOID_RSA_signingTime,
                        pSignerInfo->AuthAttrs.rgAttr[n].rgValue[0].pbData,
                        pSignerInfo->AuthAttrs.rgAttr[n].rgValue[0].cbData,
                        0,
                        (PVOID)&ft,
                        &dwData);
            if (!fResult)
            {
                _tprintf(_T("CryptDecodeObject failed with %x\n"),
                    GetLastError());
                break;
            }

            // Convert to local time.
            FileTimeToLocalFileTime(&ft, &lft);
            FileTimeToSystemTime(&lft, st);

            fReturn = TRUE;

            break; // Break from for loop.

        } //lstrcmp szOID_RSA_signingTime
    } // for 

    return fReturn;
}

BOOL GetTimeStampSignerInfo(PCMSG_SIGNER_INFO pSignerInfo, PCMSG_SIGNER_INFO *pCounterSignerInfo)
{   
    PCCERT_CONTEXT pCertContext = NULL;
    BOOL fReturn = FALSE;
    BOOL fResult;       
    DWORD dwSize;   

    __try
    {
        *pCounterSignerInfo = NULL;

        // Loop through unathenticated attributes for
        // szOID_RSA_counterSign OID.
        for (DWORD n = 0; n < pSignerInfo->UnauthAttrs.cAttr; n++)
        {
            if (lstrcmpA(pSignerInfo->UnauthAttrs.rgAttr[n].pszObjId, 
                         szOID_RSA_counterSign) == 0)
            {
                // Get size of CMSG_SIGNER_INFO structure.
                fResult = CryptDecodeObject(ENCODING,
                           PKCS7_SIGNER_INFO,
                           pSignerInfo->UnauthAttrs.rgAttr[n].rgValue[0].pbData,
                           pSignerInfo->UnauthAttrs.rgAttr[n].rgValue[0].cbData,
                           0,
                           NULL,
                           &dwSize);
                if (!fResult)
                {
                    _tprintf(_T("CryptDecodeObject failed with %x\n"),
                        GetLastError());
                    __leave;
                }

                // Allocate memory for CMSG_SIGNER_INFO.
                *pCounterSignerInfo = (PCMSG_SIGNER_INFO)LocalAlloc(LPTR, dwSize);
                if (!*pCounterSignerInfo)
                {
                    _tprintf(_T("Unable to allocate memory for timestamp info.\n"));
                    __leave;
                }

                // Decode and get CMSG_SIGNER_INFO structure
                // for timestamp certificate.
                fResult = CryptDecodeObject(ENCODING,
                           PKCS7_SIGNER_INFO,
                           pSignerInfo->UnauthAttrs.rgAttr[n].rgValue[0].pbData,
                           pSignerInfo->UnauthAttrs.rgAttr[n].rgValue[0].cbData,
                           0,
                           (PVOID)*pCounterSignerInfo,
                           &dwSize);
                if (!fResult)
                {
                    _tprintf(_T("CryptDecodeObject failed with %x\n"),
                        GetLastError());
                    __leave;
                }

                fReturn = TRUE;

                break; // Break from for loop.
            }           
        }
    }
    __finally
    {
        // Clean up.
        if (pCertContext != NULL) CertFreeCertificateContext(pCertContext);
    }

    return fReturn;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Some file formats have digital signatures applied in some way defined by the standard, and this way is not compatible with other file formats. Authenticode is one of such examples - there's a standard way to embed a signature into the EXE file in Authenticode. Other file formats like PDF or XML have own ways to embed a signature.

There exist several universal ways to make a signature, but these ways imply either a detached signature (the one stored in a separate data block) or a wrapping signature. In the latter case the original file content is "wrapped" with the signature-related data, and such file can not be handled like an original file - it's structure is different. Such universal formats are PKCS7/CMS (and CAdES), S/MIME (based on CMS), OpenPGP, XMLDSig (it can handle binary contents).

There exists no universal function which would handle all signatures in the world, though the functions that work with PKCS7/CMS seem to be the most universal (together with OpenPGP, but the latter uses its own keys, not X.509 certificates).

Our [SecureBlackbox](https://www.eldos.com/sbb/) library has methods to create and verify (and extract data from) signatures in most popular document formats and the above mentioned universal signature formats.

Comment: Well, that's all really nice. Is there any other solutions besides your paid product? Also how does it explain that the native API seems to work?

Comment: @c00000fd seems to work on what files? Please re-read my answer, seems that you've missed most part of it. The article works on Authenticode and on some proprietary formats of MS like signatures placed in comments of scripts.