# CryptQueryObject fails with CRYPT_E_NO_MATCH error in managed code but works fine in unmanaged one

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, winapi, digital-signature

I've been struggling with this bug for over a day and I appreciate if anyone could help me shed some light on it. It all started from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34281047/843732). My goal was to retrieve digital signature information on a signed `.js` file. (The file was originally signed by Microsoft's [signtool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387764(v=vs.85).aspx).)

Since my managed code seemed to have failed, I decided to try an [unmanaged approach](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/323809), in C++, which surprisingly worked just fine. So I decide to write a similar thing in C# using `PInvoke`. But no matter what I did in the managed code, that didn't work.

So I did some digging and here's the part that seems to fail.

If I do this from either 32-bit or 64-bit unmanaged C++ code, it works fine:

```
HCERTSTORE hStore = NULL;
HCRYPTMSG hMsg = NULL; 
DWORD dwEncoding = 0, dwContentType = 0, dwFormatType = 0;

// Get message handle and store handle from the signed file.
if(CryptQueryObject(CERT_QUERY_OBJECT_FILE,
                            L"D:\\Test\\DataStore\\Downloads\\en-US\\test02_1.js",
                            CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_FLAG_PKCS7_SIGNED_EMBED,
                            CERT_QUERY_FORMAT_FLAG_BINARY,
                            0,
                            &dwEncoding,
                            &dwContentType,
                            &dwFormatType,
                            &hStore,
                            &hMsg,
                            NULL))
{
    //All good
    TRACE("Got it!\n");
}
else
{
    //Failed
    TRACE("Error: 0x%x\n", ::GetLastError());
}
```

But if I do the same from an ASP.NET web application written in C# (and running as a 64-bit process on a 64-bit Windows 8.1 OS) using PInvoke, it gives me the `0x80092009` error code, or `CRYPT_E_NO_MATCH`:

```
IntPtr hStore = IntPtr.Zero;
IntPtr hMsg = IntPtr.Zero;

IntPtr dwEncoding = IntPtr.Zero, dwContentType = IntPtr.Zero, dwFormatType = IntPtr.Zero;

IntPtr DummyNull = IntPtr.Zero;

// Get message handle and store handle from the signed file.
if (!CryptQueryObject(CERT_QUERY_OBJECT_FILE,
    "D:\\Test\\DataStore\\Downloads\\en-US\\test02_1.js",
    CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_FLAG_PKCS7_SIGNED_EMBED,
    CERT_QUERY_FORMAT_FLAG_BINARY,
    0,
    dwEncoding,
    dwContentType,
    dwFormatType,
    hStore,
    hMsg,
    ref DummyNull))
{
    //Failed
    int nOSError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

    throw new Exception("Failed with error " + nOSError);
}
```

and these are `PInvoke` declarations for it:

```
        [DllImport("CRYPT32.DLL", EntryPoint = "CryptQueryObject", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern Boolean CryptQueryObject(
            Int32 dwObjectType,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string pvObject,
            Int32 dwExpectedContentTypeFlags,
            Int32 dwExpectedFormatTypeFlags,
            Int32 dwFlags,
            IntPtr pdwMsgAndCertEncodingType,
            IntPtr pdwContentType,
            IntPtr pdwFormatType,
            IntPtr phCertStore,
            IntPtr phMsg,
            ref IntPtr ppvContext
        );

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct CRYPT_OBJID_BLOB
        {
            public uint cbData;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 0)]
            public byte[] pbData;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct CRYPT_ALGORITHM_IDENTIFIER
        {
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
            public String pszObjId;
            public CRYPT_OBJID_BLOB Parameters;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct CRYPT_BIT_BLOB
        {
            public uint cbData;
            public IntPtr pbData;
            public uint cUnusedBits;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct CERT_PUBLIC_KEY_INFO
        {
            public CRYPT_ALGORITHM_IDENTIFIER Algorithm;
            public CRYPT_BIT_BLOB PublicKey;
        }

    #pragma warning disable 0618
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct CERT_INFO
        {
            public uint dwVersion;
            public CRYPT_OBJID_BLOB SerialNumber;
            public CRYPT_ALGORITHM_IDENTIFIER SignatureAlgorithm;
            public CRYPT_OBJID_BLOB Issuer;
            public FILETIME NotBefore;
            public FILETIME NotAfter;
            public CRYPT_OBJID_BLOB Subject;
            public CERT_PUBLIC_KEY_INFO SubjectPublicKeyInfo;
            public CRYPT_OBJID_BLOB IssuerUniqueId;
            public CRYPT_OBJID_BLOB SubjectUniqueId;
            public uint cExtension;
            public IntPtr rgExtension;
        }
    #pragma warning restore 0618

        private const int CERT_QUERY_OBJECT_FILE = 0x00000001;
        private const int CERT_QUERY_OBJECT_BLOB = 0x00000002;

        private const int CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_PKCS7_SIGNED_EMBED = 10;
        private const int CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_FLAG_PKCS7_SIGNED_EMBED = (1 << CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_PKCS7_SIGNED_EMBED);

        private const int CERT_QUERY_FORMAT_BINARY = 1;
        private const int CERT_QUERY_FORMAT_FLAG_BINARY = (1 << CERT_QUERY_FORMAT_BINARY);
```

Any idea why?

PS. Note that if instead of a digitally signed `.js` file, I replace it with a digitally signed `.exe` file, both managed and unmanaged code seem to work fine. And that really puzzles me!

Comment: asp.net service account has permissions on that path?

Comment: @AlexK.: Yes, I believe so. It was able to copy it there after the file was uploaded.

Comment: @AlexK.: Is there something specific to .NET context that `CryptQueryObject` is called vs. native code that makes it fail there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I haven't gotten an answer to this, let me share my current findings. First off, due to lack of replies and even a downvote from some "guru", it seems to me that people aren't really aware that one can not only digitally sign `.exe` and `.dll` files using the [SignTool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387764(v=vs.85).aspx), but also `.js`, `.vbs` and `.ps1` or PowerShell scripts, to name a few. It also appears to me that `CryptQueryObject` API relies on the extension of the digitally signed file to properly gauge the format of the signature. And for some reason the managed code seems to either rename the file it works with, or somehow make it inaccessible for the `CryptQueryObject` API.

I shared more of my thoughts on this in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34444924/843732).

Answer (score 0):

while you call CryptQueryObject to not-exe file,
you should not use  CERT_QUERY_FORMAT_FLAG_BINARY flag.
You can use CERT_QUERY_FORMAT_FLAG_ASN_ASCII_HEX_ENCODED flag for text file or
CERT_QUERY_FORMAT_FLAG_ALL for any file type;