# How to access data from inside an Azure VM?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, virtual-machine, azure-virtual-machine

Let's say I have a VM (windows) running on MS-Azure. 
Lets say I have programs Y and Z on that VM which are logging some critical data. Let's say I also have a program X inside the VM which accepts some arguments and returns some of that critical data based on filters.

Now, I am building a front end webapp, An ASP.NET website, where the owner of the above mentioned VM can login and view data that program X can provide.

I already have my logging programs running inside the VM and program X installed. How can I access an exectuble inside a VM, pass arguments to it, run it and get results back to me? is this doable? Can someone suggest how I can achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your program X doesn't involve GUI, you may try to run it on the PS Remote Session. Here is a good [guide](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff700227.aspx) about how to configure the powershell remote.

Also, here is the [article](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/christwe/2012/06/20/what-port-does-powershell-remoting-use/) about the port need opening on the firewall.

> By default PowerShell will use the following ports for communication
>   (They are the same ports as WinRM)
>
> TCP/5985 = HTTP
>
> TCP/5986 = HTTPS

If it involves GUI, as far as I know, the only solution is remoting to the VM with RDP.

Besides, it is not a good idea to expose the WinRM or RDP ports on the internet. I would suggest you to create a VPN on Azure and use WinRM or RDP over VPN.

Answer (score -1):

You can run another executable using the `System.Diagnostic.Process` class:

```
// Start the child process.
 Process p = new Process();
 // Redirect the output stream of the child process.
 p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
 p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
 p.StartInfo.FileName = "X.exe";
 p.Start();
 // Do not wait for the child process to exit before
 // reading to the end of its redirected stream.
 // p.WaitForExit();
 // Read the output stream first and then wait.
 string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
 p.WaitForExit();
```

Copied from: 
[run console application in C# with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6511978/run-console-application-in-c-sharp-with-parameters)